# Javascript strings formatting, pass methods parameter in xpath expression

Tags: javascript, string, formatting, protractor

I'm using Javascript and Protractor for my tests, and got issue in formatting string, Here is my code:

```
this.roseGold = function (metal) {
    element(by.xpath('//*[@class="rose"][contains(text(),"14K Rose Gold")]')).click()
```

How do I pass parameter `metal` instead of `"14K Rose Gold"`
In python I would do something like this:

```
this.roseGold = function (metal) {
    element(by.xpath('//*[@class="rose"][contains(text(),"%s")]' %metal)).click()
```

How can I reach that result in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to concatenate together your xpath string like so:

```
this.roseGold = function (metal) {
    element(by.xpath('//*[@class="rose"][contains(text(),"'+metal+'")]')).click();

// or use util.format(), util is a build-in module of Nodejs
var util = require('util');
this.roseGold = function (metal) {
    element(by.xpath(
       util.format('//*[@class="rose"][contains(text(),"%s")]', metal)).click();
```

That said, the Protractor style guide recommends against xpaths.

consider `element(by.cssContainingText('.rose', metal)).click();`